# Insert multiple records, where one field depends on existing values in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database table containing product reviews. One of the columns is `sort_order` – i.e. the order in which the reviews are displayed when read from the database into a web front end.

I need to batch insert a bunch of new reviews from a temporary loading table (which has been populated from a CSV) into the main reviews table. My SQL is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO reviews
(product_code, sort_order, review_date, review_text)
(SELECT product_code, 10, review_date, review_text
   FROM review_load_table)
;
```

However, of course that's not correct - it will just insert `10` in the `sort_order` column for every new review.
So, what should I have instead, if I want the value inserted into the `sort_order` field to be 1 greater than the maximum existing value for the respective product?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO reviews (product_code, sort_order, review_date, review_text)
    SELECT rlt.product_code, COALESCE(1 + rp.maxso, 1),
           rlt.review_date, rlt.review_text
    FROM review_load_table rlt LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT r.product_code, MAX(sort_order) as maxso
          FROM reviews r
          GROUP BY r.product_code
         ) rp
         ON rlt.product_code = r.product_code;
```

If you can have a product appearing multiple times in the temporary table and you want different numbers, then use `row_number()`:

```
INSERT INTO reviews (product_code, sort_order, review_date, review_text)
    SELECT rlt.product_code,
           COALESCE(rp.maxso, 0) + row_number() over (partition by rlt.product_code order by product_code),
           rlt.review_date, rlt.review_text
    FROM review_load_table rlt LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT r.product_code, MAX(sort_order) as maxso
          FROM reviews r
          GROUP BY r.product_code
         ) rp
         ON rlt.product_code = r.product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a **sequence**? It will provide uniqueness, every new value will be larger than the previous one (though, won't be gapless, but - in my opinion - you shouldn't worry about that).

This is what [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) says about it; have a look, if you're interested.

Here's a demonstration: I'm creating a sequence and two tables (reviews and review_load_table):

```
SQL> create sequence seq_sort;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table reviews
  2    (product_code  number,
  3     sort_order    number,
  4     review_text   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into reviews
  2    select 100, seq_sort.nextval, 'Text 1' from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> create table review_load_table
  2    (product_code  number,
  3     review_text   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> -- this insert simulates data loaded from the CSV file
SQL> insert into review_load_table
  2    select 100, 'Text 2' from dual union
  3    select 200, 'Text 3' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

Now, let's copy data from a temporary table:

```
SQL> insert into reviews
  2    (product_code, sort_order, review_text)
  3    (select product_code, seq_sort.nextval, review_text
  4     from review_load_table
  5    );

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from reviews order by product_code, sort_order;

PRODUCT_CODE SORT_ORDER REVIEW_TEXT
------------ ---------- --------------------
         100          1 Text 1
         100          2 Text 2
         200          3 Text 3

SQL>
```

As you can see, SORT_ORDER value is correctly set.

If you need to pre-sort rows during insert (for example, by timestamp or whichever other column), you could use a subquery which sorts first, and then apply SEQ_SORT.NEXTVAL to it:

```
insert into reviews
  (product_code, sort_order, review_text)
  (select product_code, seq_sort.nextval, review_text
   from (select product_code, review_text
         from review_load_table
         order by review_text desc
        ));
```